# Is this a bug for EKEventEditViewController

Tags: events, ios, calendar

```
I found EKEventEditViewController is not correct in 
UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpside.

Try this demo from your site, I just changed code as below, put simulator to 
UpSide Down Portrait mode, then click "+" button, you will find the screen in 
flash, this is due to dialog is upside in short time.

Then you can try it on device turn to UpSideDown mode, you will see what I am talking:)

I want to know why they have different view in Simulator or iPad even if it is 
not a bug.
```

[Bug in SimpleEKDemo](http://www.geocities.jp/mikezang/iPad/SimpleEKDemo.zip)

Comment: Don't mark regular text as code (don't put <pre> tags around it).

Answer (score 0):

Basically you would want to Create your own class that inherits from EKEventEditViewController and use that everywhere you would use normally use EKEventEditViewController.  For example, KonopEventEditViewController.

KonopEventEditViewController.h is as follows

```
#import <EventKitUI/EventKitUI.h>

@interface KonopEventEditViewController : EKEventEditViewController

@end
```

KonopEventEditViewController.m is as follows

```
#import "KonopEventEditViewController.h"

@interface KonopEventEditViewController ()

@end

@implementation KonopEventEditViewController

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return YES;
}

@end
```